# Command to filter processes by name?

Tags: command-line, process, regex

What is the command that allows the filtering of processes via a regular expression metacharacter filter?

For example, if I wanted to filter out all processes beginning with the letter `A` or `a`, how would I implement the `[Aa]$` in the overall command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command is `pgrep`.

For finding all processes that starts with `A` or `a`, only PID:

```
pgrep '^[Aa]'
```

You can use any ERE (Extended Regular Expression) pattern.

To get process name to, use `-l`:

```
pgrep -l '^[Aa]'
```

To get full command line, use `-a`:

```
pgrep -a '^[Aa]'
```

You can also match the pattern against full command line using the `-f` option.

Check `man pgrep`.

---

Just to note, your Regex pattern is wrong, the Regex token `$` match the end of a line, not start, `^` matches start. So your pattern, `[Aa]$` would match any process name (or full command line if `-f` is used) with `A` or `a` at end.

---

Also refrain from using:

```
ps -ef | grep ...
```

this is clumsy, and involves unnecessary spawning of an extra process, and an anonymous pipe where `pgrep` can do this easily, and in one go too. Moreover `pgrep` (and it's brother `pkill`) was specifically designed for this purpose.

Comment: Find only Processes that start with "C" or "c" and end with "m". (Finds all "Chromium" processes but not "Chromium Helper (Renderer)"):
´pgrep '^[Cc]hromiu[m]$'´

Answer (score -1):

```
ps ax| grep name_of_processes
```

For example:

```
$ ps ax |grep python

1393 pts/2    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto python
1713 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/mintupdate-launcher
1727 ?        Sl     0:01 /usr/bin/python3        /usr/lib/linuxmint/mintUpdate/mintUpdate.py
```

Quickest way I'm used to do and you can see the number of processes to kill if you want.

In your cases, to eliminate the grep process, you can use brackets as part of your pattern:

```
ps -ef | grep '[t]ty'
```

Comment: How is this matching OP's condition?

Comment: @heemayl Edited

Comment: Still no. The question is _I wanted to filter out all processes beginning with the letter A or a_